# Is there bullet drop on any other gun besides sniper rifles?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

There are currently three sniper rifles:

- Heavy sniper
- Bolt action sniper
- Semi-auto sniper

At great distances each of the above will experience some form of bullet drop. What about other, non-sniper guns (e.g. hunting rifles, assault rifles, pistols) - do these have bullet drop similar to sniper rifles?

If so can they be expected to experience similar bullet drop to regular snipers or are they all different from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Bullet drop on all the snipers you listed along with hunting rifles and the quad launcher. On all other gun the bullets disappear after a while.